# Want to create 2 columns with different period parameters from the same data in SSRS

Tags: postgresql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I want to create a monthly report, calculating the % from the previous 2 month average from the previous 12 months average. Basically I want to see which shops have dropped in sales in the previous 2 months, and hopefully only show the shops that have decreased 20% in sales.

So i believe the columns need to be like this

```
Shop|Products|Avg of 12 months|Avg of 2 months| %
```

Since i have many entries for the sales, i also need to sum the previous 12 months and then average it... as well as sum the previous 2 months and average it

I have thought of some ways to do it, but it didnt seem to work and seems all too complicated and complex.

Im hoping if there is a simpler solution to this? Do i need to use pivot table?

I'm using PostGres 9.1 on Visual Studio 10

Thanks a bunch

Comment: do you want to print your report for a SINGLE month (i.e. july 2013 so avg from 07/2012 to 06/2013 and avg from 05/2013 to 06/2013) or for a period of months?

Comment: @tezzo a single month is fine, end goal is to find the % and then sort it by the smallest - largest. thanks

Comment: what are the methods that you think so far? so I can try to answer with a simpler solution...

Comment: I thought of actually creating 2 datasets and then filtering by the dates to get 2 columns, but i wont be able to put it in 1 table since 2 datasets cannot exist...

Comment: Would it be easier to create a sub report for both periods, and then submit it into a main report?

Answer (score 1):

When something seems too complicated to resolve with a single query, I create and populate a DataTable runtime and pass it to ReportViewer.

In this case you can:

1. create a DataTable with Shop and Product as a PK (if you want print the report for a period of months you can also add Month as PK). The other 2 columns will be Avg12Months and Avg2Months
2. insert a record for each combination of Shop/Product (and eventually Month)
3. for each record Shop/Product calculate and save the results for Avg12Months and Avg2Months
4. pass your DataTable to ReportViewer
5. use a single Tablix to display the results (sort, grouping and other operations can be done in the Tablix)

Some passages can be combined in order to speed up the process.

Comment: What is a DataTable and how do i use it? I have almost no knowledge databases and started using SSRS like 3 weeks ago

Comment: this is a good starting point to learn about DataSet and DataTable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ss7fbaez.aspx